# Mutate based on partial string with spaces

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

In the below string, I only want to extract the value that matches "Left" and "Right", and excludes the rest using `mutate()`. Let's pretend I have a dataset `data` with a column called `string`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data$string <- c("Left A", "Left Middle A", "Middle A", "Right Middle A", "Right A",
                 "Left B", "Left Middle B", "Middle B", "Right Middle B", "Right B")

data1 <- data %>%
  mutate(Location = ifelse(gsub("\\bLeft\\b", string) | gsub("\\bRight\\b", string),
                           "Out",
                           "In"))
```

But due to the spaces, it returns everything with "Left" and "Right" in the string. How can I get it to recognize that I only want it to match that first word and not anything after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match "Middle" (Note this is true for your first dataset, for the second and a more general solution see below):

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Location = if_else(grepl("Middle", string), "In", "Out"))

      string Location
1         Left A      Out
2  Left Middle A       In
3       Middle A       In
4 Right Middle A       In
5        Right A      Out
```

To have a more general approach, we could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>%
  mutate(helper = ifelse(str_count(string, "\\b\\w+\\b") == 3, paste(word(string, 1), word(string,3)), string)) %>% 
  mutate(Location = if_else(str_detect(helper, "Left|Right"), "Out", "In"), .keep = "unused")
```

Or:
More concise with a sequential `if_else`

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    Location = if_else(
      str_detect(
        if_else(str_count(string, "\\b\\w+\\b") == 3, paste(word(string, 1), word(string, 3)), string),
        "Left|Right"
      ),
      "Out",
      "In"
    )
  )
```

```
  string Location
1          Left A      Out
2   Left Middle A      Out
3        Middle A       In
4  Right Middle A      Out
5         Right A      Out
6          Left B      Out
7   Left Middle B      Out
8        Middle B       In
9  Right Middle B      Out
10        Right B      Out
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually want "Left Middle A", "Middle A", and "Right Middle A" to be classified as "In", and "Left A" and "Right A" to be classified as "Out." How do I achieve that?

Comment: `data %>%
  mutate(Location = if_else(grepl("Middle", string), "In", "Out"))`

Comment: Gah, of course! Should've recognized that I could just match "Middle." Too many hours in R. Thank you again so much!

Comment: Also, thank you for the update providing the general way! Will use this often.